# Subsetting with pd.Series.isin: way to keep all values?

Tags: python, pandas

My function uses bitwise AND and pd.Series.isin to subset a pd.DataFrame according to whether its column values "are in" sets of items specified by the user. A stylized example:

```
my_data = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "CLASS": "ALGEBRA",
            "DIFFICULTY": "HARD",
            "TEACHER": "JOHN",
        },
        {
            "CLASS": "CS",
            "DIFFICULTY": "HARD",
            "TEACHER": "JILL",
        },
        {
            "CLASS": "ENGLISH",
            "DIFFICULTY": "HARD",
            "TEACHER": "JOHN",
        },
    ]
)


def identify_teachers(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    classes: Iterable[str],
    difficulties: Iterable[str],
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.loc[
        df["CLASS"].isin(classes)
        & df["DIFFICULTY"].isin(difficulties),
        "TEACHER",
    ]


identify_teachers(
    df=my_data,
    classes=["ALGEBRA", "ENGLISH"],
    difficulties=["HARD"],
)
```

What if the user seeks to identify all teachers of difficult classes, without knowing the full list of classes? Within this construct it seems I would need a helper function like the following:

```
def generalized_filter(s: pd.Series, items: Optional[Iterable[Any]] = None) -> pd.Series:
    if items is None:
        return s
    else:
       return s[s.isin(items)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build all the filter conditions into a list, then use `reduce` to chain the AND filter on them:

```py
import functools


def identify_teachers(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    classes: Iterable[str] = None,
    difficulties: Iterable[str] = None,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    filters = []
    if classes:
        filters.append(df["CLASS"].isin(classes))
    if difficulties:
        filters.append(
            df["DIFFICULTY"].isin(difficulties)
        )
    if not filters:
        return None  # or all rows? You choose :)
    filter_expr = functools.reduce(
        lambda a, b: a & b, filters
    )

    return df.loc[filter_expr, "TEACHER"]
```